# How to decrypt a mac encrypted external HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, mac

I have an external HDD that I encrypted on a mac HighSierra and I would like to decrypt it on Ubuntu 17.10. Is there any way to do that? I would highly appreciate any help with this!

The file system is Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled, Encrypted) and I used the Disk Utility on Mac to encrypt it. I also posses the encryption key I used to encrypt the HDD.

Comment: You will have to figure out how the Mac Disk Utility encrypts things (on a Mac forum, not on AskUbuntu), then ask a more detailed question.